# How to track user in android Oreo and above version

Tags: android, service, android-workmanager, background-foreground

I want to track user every 30 minutes in android Oreo version. Tracking services are getting stopped when the user is killing from recent app tray. I tried using **Foreground Service/Work Manager** which work fine in Pie but the same are not working for Oreo.

> Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleService.class);
>   serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", input);
>   ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this,serviceIntent);

ExampleService.Java

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {

    private Timer mTimer;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private static final int TIMER_INTERVAL = 120000; // 2 Minute
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (mTimer != null)
            mTimer = null;

        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new DisplayToastTimerTask(), TIMER_DELAY, TIMER_INTERVAL);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String input=intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");

        Intent notificationIntent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,
                notificationIntent,0);
        Notification notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Example Service")
                .setContentText(input)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();
        startForeground(1, notification);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        startAgainService();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        startAgainService();
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private class DisplayToastTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Hello world every 5 minute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void startAgainService() {
        Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
        restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

        PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
                restartServicePendingIntent);           
    }
}
```

Comment: Who is the manufacturer of the device?

Comment: OnePlus, Mi etc.

Comment: This is a problem with manufacturers that add custom android, if you try to run this on stock android this will not happen, unfortunately i don't think there are any solution for this (i have same problem and spent days to find something)

Answer (score 0):

Some device manufacturers have decided to modify stock Android to force-stop the app when the user swipe it out from the recent application.

As reported on WorkManager's public issuetracker - [*are the Chinese manufacturers (Huawei, Oppo, Xiaomi...) supported?*](https://issuetracker.google.com/113676489), there is no way to work around this.

In these cases your work will stop till the user launch again your app.